# Hamming codes formulas

Tags: hamming-code

This is the question:

*Determine if the Hamming codes (15,10), (14,10) and (13,10) can correct a single error (SEC), detect a single error (SED) or detect double bit errors (DED).*

I do know how Hamming distance work and how you can detect an error if you have the data-word that you want to transmit. But I don't know how to do it without the data-word.

Only for SEC which has the formula:

2^m > m+k+1

where

m = check bits
k = data bits

But is the any formulas for SED and DED? I have searched google all day long without any success.

Answer (score 1):

I learned how to solve it checks the Hamming codes through this Youtube clip. there is no effective way. wish there was a faster way to solve the problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAMLuxdHH8o

This is not responding properly to the question because I know what the user 
"user3314356" needs, but I could not comment because I did not have 50 reputation points!.